# How do I make my UIImageView automatically scale while having a fixed width?

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I have a lot of different sized images that I want to display inside of a UIScrollView. I always want the images to be displayed at 300px wide with a variable height (to keep the aspect ratio).

I tried a bunch of things, but nothing works. I either get the images cut off on the sides or squished.

Any ideas?

Any code or examples greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some built-in functions in iOS that allow you to look at image data (take a look at [Apple's Developer Notes on CGImage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGImage/Reference/reference.html). For this instance, if you have a

```
UIImage *imageObj = [UIImage imageNamed:@"whatever.png"];
```

You can find the height and/or width CGGetImageWidth/CGGetImageHeight:

```
size_t pixelsWide = CGImageGetWidth(imageObj.CGImage);
size_t pixelsHigh = CGImageGetHeight(imageObj.CGImage);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"img.jpg"];
```

... where `image` is, let's say 1280 * 720px

300/1280 = 0.234375

This is our scale factor that we'll use and multiply the height by, to match your target width of 300px.

0.234375 * 720 = 168.75px height

Thus, our 1280 * 720px image goes to 300 * 169px. (rounded)

Comment: You need to acquire the image in some form though, whether the source is downloaded and saved as a temp file or if it goes straight into a class such as UIImage.

Comment: yeah, they're all in the bundle... but there are hundreds and i don't want to hard code logic for all of them.

Comment: Are they (filenames or similar) in an array or literally just tons in your bundle? You can probably still write a loop to browse your bundle contents to accomplish this. Also you really need to pad out your original question.... "lots" of images doesn't sound like hundreds to me ;)